# Testing DocuSign webhooks with a connect key

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am using DocuSign Connect to retrieve webhooks from DocuSign and digest them within my Larave; application. Here is the basic idea.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyDocusignWebhookSignature;
use App\Mail\PaymentRequired;
use App\Models\PaymentAttempt;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DocusignWebhookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     * If a DocuSign Connect key is preset, validate the request.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->gocardlessTabs = ['GoCardless Agreement Number', 'GoCardless Amount', 'GoCardless Centre'];
        $this->assumedCustomer = 2;

        if (config('docusign.connect_key')) {
            $this->middleware(VerifyDocusignWebhookSignature::class);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming DocuSign webhook.
     */
    public function handleWebhook(Request $request)
    {
        $payload = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $shouldProcessWebhook = $this->determineIfEnvelopeRelevant($payload);

        if ($shouldProcessWebhook) {
            switch ($payload['status']) {
                case 'sent':
                    return $this->handleSentEnvelopeStatus($payload);
                break;
                case 'completed':
                    return $this->handleCompletedEnvelopeStatus($payload);
                break;
                case 'voided':
                // ...
                break;
                default:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logic itself works fine but if you look here:

```
if (config('docusign.connect_key')) {
    $this->middleware(VerifyDocusignWebhookSignature::class);
}
```

If I specify a connect key I run some middleware to verify the webhook came from DocuSign.

The class to verify the signature came from DocuSign and looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\DocuSign;

/**
 * This class is used to validate HMAC keys sent from DocuSign webhooks.
 * For more information see: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/hmac/
 *
 * Class taken from: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/validate/
 *
 * Sample headers
 * [X-Authorization-Digest, HMACSHA256]
 * [X-DocuSign-AccountId, caefc2a3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-073c9681515f]
 * [X-DocuSign-Signature-1, DfV+OtRSnsuy.....NLXUyTfY=]
 * [X-DocuSign-Signature-2, CL9zR6MI/yUa.....O09tpBhk=]
 */
class HmacVerifier
{
    /**
     * Compute a hmac hash from the given payload.
     *
     * Useful reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php
     * NOTE: Currently DocuSign only supports SHA256.
     *
     * @param string $secret
     * @param string $payload
     */
    public static function computeHash($secret, $payload)
    {
        $hexHash = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, utf8_encode($secret));
        $base64Hash = base64_encode(hex2bin($hexHash));

        return $base64Hash;
    }

    /**
     * Validate that a given hash is valid.
     *
     * @param string $secret:  the secret known only by our application
     * @param string $payload: the payload received from the webhook
     * @param string $verify:  the string we want to verify in the request header
     */
    public static function validateHash($secret, $payload, $verify)
    {
        return hash_equals($verify, self::computeHash($secret, $payload));
    }
}
```

Now, in order to test this locally I've written a test but whenever I run it, the middleware tells me the webhook isn't valid.

Here is my test class

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Feature\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Tests\TestCase;

class VerifyDocusignWebhookSignatureTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        config(['docusign.connect_key' => 'probably-best-not-put-on-stack-overflow']);

        $this->docusignConnectKey = config('docusign.connect_key');
    }

    /**
     * Given a JSON payload, can we parse it and do what we need to do?
     *
     * @test
     */
    public function it_can_retrieve_a_webhook_with_a_connect_key()
    {
        Mail::fake();

        $payload = '{"status":"sent","documentsUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514/documents","recipientsUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514/recipients","attachmentsUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514/attachments","envelopeUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514","emailSubject":"Please DocuSign: newflex doc test.docx","envelopeId":"2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514","signingLocation":"online","customFieldsUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514/custom_fields","notificationUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514/notification","enableWetSign":"true","allowMarkup":"false","allowReassign":"true","createdDateTime":"2022-02-14T11:36:01.18Z","lastModifiedDateTime":"2022-02-14T11:37:48.633Z","initialSentDateTime":"2022-02-14T11:37:49.477Z","sentDateTime":"2022-02-14T11:37:49.477Z","statusChangedDateTime":"2022-02-14T11:37:49.477Z","documentsCombinedUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514/documents/combined","certificateUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514/documents/certificate","templatesUri":"/envelopes/2ba67e2f-0db6-46af-865a-e217c9a1c514/templates","expireEnabled":"true","expireDateTime":"2022-06-14T11:37:49.477Z","expireAfter":"120","sender":{"userName":"Newable eSignature","userId":"f947420b-6897-4f29-80b3-4deeaf73a3c5","accountId":"366e9845-963a-41dd-9061-04f61c921f28","email":"e-signature@newable.co.uk"},"recipients":{"signers":[{"tabs":{"textTabs":[{"validationPattern":"","validationMessage":"","shared":"false","requireInitialOnSharedChange":"false","requireAll":"false","value":"","required":"true","locked":"false","concealValueOnDocument":"false","disableAutoSize":"false","maxLength":"4000","tabLabel":"GoCardless Amount","font":"lucidaconsole","fontColor":"black","fontSize":"size9","localePolicy":{},"documentId":"1","recipientId":"56041698","pageNumber":"1","xPosition":"319","yPosition":"84","width":"84","height":"22","tabId":"207f970c-4d3c-4d0c-be6b-1f3aeecf5f95","tabType":"text"},{"validationPattern":"","validationMessage":"","shared":"false","requireInitialOnSharedChange":"false","requireAll":"false","value":"","required":"true","locked":"false","concealValueOnDocument":"false","disableAutoSize":"false","maxLength":"4000","tabLabel":"GoCardless Centre","font":"lucidaconsole","fontColor":"black","fontSize":"size9","localePolicy":{},"documentId":"1","recipientId":"56041698","pageNumber":"1","xPosition":"324","yPosition":"144","width":"84","height":"22","tabId":"f6919e94-d4b7-4ef4-982d-3fc6c16024ab","tabType":"text"},{"validationPattern":"","validationMessage":"","shared":"false","requireInitialOnSharedChange":"false","requireAll":"false","value":"","required":"true","locked":"false","concealValueOnDocument":"false","disableAutoSize":"false","maxLength":"4000","tabLabel":"GoCardless Agreement Number","font":"lucidaconsole","fontColor":"black","fontSize":"size9","localePolicy":{},"documentId":"1","recipientId":"56041698","pageNumber":"1","xPosition":"332","yPosition":"200","width":"84","height":"22","tabId":"9495a53c-1f5e-42a5-beec-9abcf77b4387","tabType":"text"}]},"creationReason":"sender","isBulkRecipient":"false","requireUploadSignature":"false","name":"Jesse","firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"Jesse.Orange@newable.co.uk","recipientId":"56041698","recipientIdGuid":"246ce44f-0c11-4632-ac24-97f31911594e","requireIdLookup":"false","userId":"b23ada8e-577e-4517-b0fa-e6d8fd440f21","routingOrder":"1","note":"","status":"sent","completedCount":"0","deliveryMethod":"email","totalTabCount":"3","recipientType":"signer"},{"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"stampType":"signature","name":"SignHere","tabLabel":"Signature 7ac0c7c8-f838-4674-9e37-10a0df2f81c1","scaleValue":"1","optional":"false","documentId":"1","recipientId":"38774161","pageNumber":"1","xPosition":"161","yPosition":"275","tabId":"371bc702-1a91-4b71-8c77-a2e7abe3210e","tabType":"signhere"}]},"creationReason":"sender","isBulkRecipient":"false","requireUploadSignature":"false","name":"Jesse Orange","firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"jesseorange360@gmail.com","recipientId":"38774161","recipientIdGuid":"844f781c-1516-4a5a-821a-9d8fb2319369","requireIdLookup":"false","userId":"f544f7ff-91bb-4175-894e-b42ce736f273","routingOrder":"2","note":"","status":"created","completedCount":"0","deliveryMethod":"email","totalTabCount":"1","recipientType":"signer"}],"agents":[],"editors":[],"intermediaries":[],"carbonCopies":[],"certifiedDeliveries":[],"inPersonSigners":[],"seals":[],"witnesses":[],"notaries":[],"recipientCount":"2","currentRoutingOrder":"1"},"purgeState":"unpurged","envelopeIdStamping":"true","is21CFRPart11":"false","signerCanSignOnMobile":"true","autoNavigation":"true","isSignatureProviderEnvelope":"false","hasFormDataChanged":"false","allowComments":"true","hasComments":"false","allowViewHistory":"true","envelopeMetadata":{"allowAdvancedCorrect":"true","enableSignWithNotary":"false","allowCorrect":"true"},"anySigner":null,"envelopeLocation":"current_site","isDynamicEnvelope":"false"}';

        // Compute a hash as in production this will come from DocuSign
        $hash = $this->computeHash($this->docusignConnectKey, $payload);

        // Validate the hash as we're going to use it as the header
        $this->assertTrue($this->validateHash($this->docusignConnectKey, $payload, $hash));

        // Convert this response to an array for the test
        $payload = json_decode($payload, true);

        // Post as JSON as Laravel only accepts POSTing arrays
        $this->postJson(route('webhook-docusign'), $payload, [
            'x-docusign-signature-3' => $hash
        ])->assertStatus(200);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('payment_attempts', [
            'envelope_id' => $payload['envelopeId']
        ]);

        Mail::assertNothingSent();
    }

    /**
     * As we're testing we need a way to verify the signature so we're computing the hash.
     */
    private function computeHash($secret, $payload)
    {
        $hexHash = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, utf8_encode($secret));
        $base64Hash = base64_encode(hex2bin($hexHash));

        return $base64Hash;
    }

    /**
     * Validate that a given hash is valid.
     *
     * @param string $secret:  the secret known only by our application
     * @param string $payload: the payload received from the webhook
     * @param string $verify:  the string we want to verify in the request header
     */
    private function validateHash($secret, $payload, $verify)
    {
        return hash_equals($verify, self::computeHash($secret, $payload));
    }
}
```

I'm also using webhook.site to compare hashes:

[image]

Given this I can tell you that `x-docusign-signature-3` matches the hash I generate when I run

`$hash = $this->computeHash($this->docusignConnectKey, $payload);`

So, my issue surely must stem from the way I'm sending the data back through?

Comment: Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Many thanks!!***

Answer (score 1):

When you compute your own HMAC on the incoming payload (to see if it matches the HMAC that was sent in the header), you must use the incoming payload as is.

In your code:

```
public function handleWebhook(Request $request)
{
    $payload = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    $shouldProcessWebhook = $this->determineIfEnvelopeRelevant($payload);
```

you are sending the json decoded payload to your check method. That is not right, you should send the raw payload, as it arrived.

(Decoding, then encoding JSON doesn't necessarily give you the same byte sequence as the original.)

The JSON decode method should only be applied to the payload **after** you've confirmed that the payload came from DocuSign.

***Plus,*** doing the JSON decode before you've authenticated the sender is a security issue. A bad guy could be trying to send you some bad input. The rule is trust nothing until you've verified the sender (via the HMAC in this case).

#### Bonus comment

I recommend that you also configure DocuSign Connect webhook's Basic Authentication feature. Basic Authentication is often checked at the web server level. HMAC, since it must be computed, is usually check at the app level. Using both provides solid defense against bad guys.

Comment: Hi, the only thing I would mention is that I'm verifying the signature through middleware that actually runs in the constructor before even calling handleWebhook(). I think my issue actually stems from the fact that in my test, when I use `postJson` it escapes the array, adding a bunch of slashes everywhere. As you pointed out, if I use the actual raw content in the Hmac verifier it works just fine.

Comment: Agreed, it is critical to use the incoming bytes, as is, for HMAC and similar checksum calculations.